# Laravel Set Session or Token for External User Login Successfully - No User Database Only Api user

Tags: php, laravel, session, jwt, token

I am pulling User Information from an external site with external API. I have completed the user login route on the Laravel and I get the data from the controller file. There is no problem in terms of pulling and displaying data from an external user API link.

How to do token and session operation like regular Laravel user to the user logged in with external API without the database. Note that I can use the same token part of the user API token available

In addition, I don't want to transfer the information by assigning session between the controller each time the user was login. How do I assign tokens in all transactions after user login?

It comes to these controls via post method from login screen

```php
public function loginData(Request $request)
    {

        $password = $request->password;
        $email = $request->email;
        $apiman = "Bearer {$this->accesstokenApi()}";
        $client = new Client();
        $response = $client->post('https://testapi.com/api/v3/Profile', [
            'headers' => 
            [
                'cache-control' => 'no-cache', 
                'authorization' => $apiman, 
                'content-type'  => 'application/json'
            ],
            'json' => 
            [
                'Email' => $email,
                'Password' => $password
            ],

        ]);
        $data = json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);


        if ($data['ResponseType']=="Ok") {
            session()->put('token', $data);
            return redirect('/user-detail');
        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'Invalid Email or Password',
            ], 401);
        }
    }
```

User logged in OK . After that, what token should the machine give, or where can the session be given to that user in one place? Besides, if the user is logged in, how do I get him to see the home page instead of showing the login form again, just like in Laravel login processes ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create new middleware that will check if there is a token in the session

Here is the example that you can use and adapt it based on your needs.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Myauth
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if(session()->has('token')) {
            return $next($request);    
        } else {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            //OR return redirect()->guest('/');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont think you need a else statement here